# Magento 1.9 set default 'Qty' to 100 and 'Stock Availability' to Blank

Tags: magento-1.9.2.1, default-values, qty

In magento 1.9 I need to set the default **qty** value to 100 and **Stock Availability** to blank while creating a duplicate product.

So when a user duplicates a product, he should see **qty** value as 100 and **Stock Availability** as blank within **inventory** tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this I have copied the following file `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php`

And added the following code inside `duplicate()` method just before `$newProduct->save();` line:

```
 $newProduct->setStockData(
   array( 
          'is_in_stock' => 3, 
          'qty' => 100,
   )
 );
```